# Is brightness temperature from GEE USGS Landsat 7 Surface Reflectance Tier 1, top of atmosphere brightness temperature?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I was wondering if the brightness temperature from band 6 of USGS Landsat 7 Surface Reflectance Tier 1 product in Google Earth Engine Top of Atmosphere Brightness Temperature?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format. Then please [edit] your question to include detail about any attempt(s) you've made to answer your own question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: May I ask if it is (GEE USGS Landsat 7 Surface Reflectance Tier 1, top of atmosphere brightness temperature) corrected for solar effects? In Ledaps Product Guide, it states "Band 6 TOA Brightness Temperature is derived from TOA radiance and two thermal constants, as described on https://www.usgs.gov/land-resources/nli/landsat/using-usgslandsat-level-1-data-product".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/164931)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Band 6 is the top-of-atmosphere brightness temperature.

This can be found from the Earth Engine dataset description page for [USGS Landsat 7 Surface Reflectance Tier 1](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LE07_C01_T1_SR), which links to the data provider's (USGS's) product guide 
[LANDSAT 4-7 SURFACE REFLECTANCE (LEDAPS) PRODUCT GUIDE](https://landsat.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/documents/ledaps_product_guide.pdf) which defines the product bands. Section 3.5 is relevant:

> *3.5 Band 6 Top of Atmosphere Brightness Temperature*
>
> This option delivers the TOA Brightness Temperature (BT) for thermal Band 6, which
>   is converted to Kelvin.